# if elseif php simple calculator

Tags: php, forms, if-statement, calculator

This is form for calculator

```
<form method='post' action='result.php' name='calc_form'>

<input type='text' name='input1' size='15'>

<select name='operation'>
<option value="plus">+</option>
<option value="minus">-</option>
<option value="multi">*</option>
<option value="invalid">**</option>
<option value="divide">/</option>
</select>  

<input type='text' name='input2' size='15'>
<input type='submit' value='go'>


</form>
```

This is php with if elseif statement

```
<?php

define ('INVALID_INPUT', 'ERROR: invalid input');
define ('INVALID_OPERATOR', 'ERROR: invalid operator');


$result = null;

if 
(isset($_POST) and 
isset($_POST['input1']) and 
isset($_POST['input2']) and 
isset($_POST['operation']))
  {
  $input1 = $_POST['input1'];   
  $input2 = $_POST['input2'];
  $operation = $_POST['operation'];
     switch ($operation)
       {
       case 'plus':
         $result = $input1 + $input2;
         break;
       case 'minus':
         $result = $input1 - $input2;
         break;
       case 'multi':
         $result = $input1 * $input2;
         break;
       case 'divide':
         $result = $input1 / $input2;
         break;
       default: 
         $result = INVALID_OPERATOR;           
         break;
       }
    }  
elseif
(!isset($_POST) and 
isset($_POST['input1']) and 
isset($_POST['input2']) and 
isset($_POST['operation']))
{  
$result = INVALID_INPUT;
}

if ($result !== null)
{
echo <<<EOM


<h2>you calculate</h2> $input1 

<h2>and</h2>  $input2 

<h2>result is:</h2>

$result

EOM;
 }
```

?>

I even tried with only else statement and without condition but it wont show INVALID INPUT when nothing is added in form. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with this piece of code:

```
if 
(isset($_POST) and 
isset($_POST['input1']) and 
isset($_POST['input2']) and 
isset($_POST['operation']))
```

Even if a user enters nothing in the input fields, they will still pass `isset($_POST['input1'])`, since they are 'set' to an empty string. Try switching it to this instead:

```
if 
(isset($_POST['input1']) && strlen($_POST['input1']) &&
 isset($_POST['input2']) && strlen($_POST['input2']) &&
 isset($_POST['operation']))
```

Comment: Yes this works fine. Just this peace of code missing to avoid php notice $input1 = $input2 = $result = null;

Answer (score 2):

You could just use an else statement instead of an else if statement. That way if you change the inputs you don't have to list each of them twice.

eg:

```
if (isset($_POST) and 
isset($_POST['input1']) and 
isset($_POST['input2']) and 
isset($_POST['operation'])) 
{
    // result = calculation
} else
{
    // result == code
}
```

Try this - I tested this on my server and it works!

calculator.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors',1);;

define ('INVALID_INPUT', 'ERROR: invalid input');
define ('INVALID_OPERATOR', 'ERROR: invalid operator');
$input1 = $input2 = $operation = null;
if (isset($_POST['input1']) and  isset($_POST['input2']) and isset($_POST['operation']))
  {

    $input1 = $_POST['input1'];   
    $input2 = $_POST['input2'];
    $operation = $_POST['operation'];
    if(is_numeric($input1) and is_numeric($input2))
    {
       switch ($operation)
       {
       case 'plus':
         $result = $input1 + $input2;
         break;
       case 'minus':
         $result = $input1 - $input2;
         break;
       case 'multi':
         $result = $input1 * $input2;
         break;
       case 'divide':
         $result = $input1 / $input2;
         break;
       default: 
         $result = INVALID_OPERATOR;           
         break;
       }
    }
    else 
    {
        $input1 = '';
        $input2 = '';
        $operation = 'invalid';
        $result = INVALID_INPUT;
    }  
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body class="">

<form method='POST' action='calculator.php'>

<input type='text' name='input1' size='15' value="<?php echo $input1; ?>">

<select name='operation'>
<option <?php if($operation == 'plus') { echo 'selected';} ?> value="plus">+</option>
<option <?php if($operation == 'minus') { echo 'selected';} ?> value="minus">-</option>
<option <?php if($operation == 'multi') { echo 'selected';} ?> value="multi">*</option>
<option <?php if($operation == 'invalid') { echo 'selected';} ?> value="invalid">**</option>
<option <?php if($operation == 'divide') { echo 'selected';} ?> value="divide">/</option>
</select>  

<input type='text' name='input2' size='15' value="<?php echo $input2; ?>">
<span>=</span>
<input type='text' name='result' size='50' value="<?php echo $result; ?>">

<input type='submit' value='go'>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Result is the same, it shows zero instead of INVALID INPUT

Comment: It is different markup but yes it works fine. Just add $input1 = $input2 = $operation = $result = null; result variable in that code line.

Comment: I forgot to change the method from get to post.

Answer (score 1):

Your condition is wrong; this is impossible:

```
!isset($_POST) and 
isset($_POST['input1']) and 
isset($_POST['input2']) and 
isset($_POST['operation'])
```

I suspect you mean

```
!isset($_POST) or 
!isset($_POST['input1']) or 
!isset($_POST['input2']) or 
!isset($_POST['operation'])
```

Comment: I tried this but it shows zero as result when form is empty instead of INVALID INPUT